# I need help to this math problem with code verify?

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript script about the memory card game 4 x 4. I have a memory game with 16 boxes. On the game, they are 2 similar cards. In total 8 different couples. I should know how many combinations I have in total like:
A COMBINATION
x stay at 1 and x stay at last position.

B COMBINATION
y stay at 2 and y stay at 3 position

C COMBINATION
y stay at 1 and y stay at last position.

Combination A and C are the same: I don't care if its x or y I care about the position,
There 2 combinations ( A an C)

```
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.memory-card');

let hasFlippedCard = false;
let lockBoard = false;
let firstCard, secondCard;

function flipCard() {
  if (lockBoard) return;
  if (this === firstCard) return;

  this.classList.add('flip');

  if (!hasFlippedCard) {
    hasFlippedCard = true;
    firstCard = this;

    return;
  }

  secondCard = this;
  checkForMatch();
}

function checkForMatch() {
  let isMatch = firstCard.dataset.framework === secondCard.dataset.framework;

  isMatch ? disableCards() : unflipCards();
}

function disableCards() {
  firstCard.removeEventListener('click', flipCard);
  secondCard.removeEventListener('click', flipCard);

  resetBoard();
}

function unflipCards() {
  lockBoard = true;

  setTimeout(() => {
    firstCard.classList.remove('flip');
    secondCard.classList.remove('flip');

    resetBoard();
  }, 1500);
}

function resetBoard() {
  [hasFlippedCard, lockBoard] = [false, false];
  [firstCard, secondCard] = [null, null];
}

(function shuffle() {
  cards.forEach(card => {
    let randomPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12);
    card.style.order = randomPos;
  });
})();`enter code here`

cards.forEach(card => card.addEventListener('click', flipCard));
```

i want to add something that updates automatically every time the memory and memorizes every combination of position in lines that are memorized on a file

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. I don't see any actual question(s).

Comment: i want to add something that updates automatically every time the memory and memorizes every combination of position in lines that are memorized on a file.

Comment: I have no clue what you mean by “combinations” here in the first place, please explain that properly.

Comment: The combination is like mix of cards.A combination  is  like: Alghrotim  1 has           : a  b  b  a,    algorithm 2  has : a  b a  b     , algorithm 3 has : b a b a   ( algorithm 2 and 3 has the same combination same sequence).I dont care if i  numbers letters or else , i just care about the sequence of it.

Comment: If you want to know how to calculate the number of combinations, SO is not the dedicated place (maybe https://math.stackexchange.com/ ?). If on the contrary you have trouble implementing it in code, then your question should reflect it more (i see nothing about calculating combinations or using a file in current code)